# Why does Apache ignore my Directory block?

Tags: apache-2.2

I just moved my projects into a new workstation. I'm having trouble getting my Apache installation to acknowledge my `.htaccess` files. This is my `/etc/apache2/conf.d/dev` config file:

```
<Directory /home/codemonkey/dev/myproject/>
    Options -Indexes
    AllowOverride All

    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

I know the config file is being included by Apache because it complains if I put erroneous syntax in it (Action 'configtest' fails).

My project is reachable through Apache by a symlink in the `/var/www` directory. The server is running with my user and group, so it has my permissions. My entire `dev` folder has permissions set to `770` recursively.

Despite all this, I'm still getting an indexed display of my project folder when I visit `http://localhost/myproject`. Why isn't the above config making it impossible to view the folder in the browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As clearly documented, symlinks followed by apache [***do not transfer access responsibility to the target directory.***](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options)

Comment: Good to know. Changing line 1 in my config file to `<Directory /var/www/myproject/>` worked

Answer (score 0):

Because apache sees this directory as `/var/www/myproject`, not `/home/codemonkey/dev/myproject/` because it is a symlink. To fix this, just put the `-Indexes` in an .htaccess file in your myproject dir.